# Inverse matrix not possible

Tags: r

I'm trying to produce the inverse of a covariance matrix. Up to now I have:

```
A<- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
B<- c(8, 4, 1, 4)
C<- c(9, 2, 4, 6)
D<- c(1, 4, 2, 0)
M<- matrix(c(A, B, C, D), 4)    
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    8    9    1
[2,]    3    4    2    4
[3,]    5    1    4    2
[4,]    7    4    6    0
> 

> M<- cov(M)
> M
          [,1]  [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  6.666667 -5.00 -2.333333 -1.666667
[2,] -5.000000  8.25  6.250000 -1.250000
[3,] -2.333333  6.25  8.916667 -3.916667
[4,] -1.666667 -1.25 -3.916667  2.916667
```

But then a problem arises:

```
> M<- solve(M)
Error in solve.default(M) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[4,4] = 0
```

Where did I do something wrong?

Background is that I want to apply the [mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) and there one has to draw an inverse matrix of the covariance matrix. 
The covariance matrix is allowed to have negative entries, what about the inverse then?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that the covariance matrix should be invertible? It's determinant is zero...

Comment: Shouldn't be every matrix invertible?

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)

Comment: Ah, ok, just looked it up..  so a matrix must have a determinant not equal to 0.

Comment: with Mahalanobis distance you should be OK using a Moore-Penrose inverse which will work even if your matrix is singular, see discussion here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37743/singular-covariance-matrix-in-mahalanobis-distance-in-matlab). Function in R is `ginv()` from MASS library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is not invertible because it is [singular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularMatrix.html). There are several ways to check for this, but one of the simplest is to check if the determinant is zero. When this happens, the matrix does not have an inverse.

Think of a singular matrix as something like zero, and think of taking the inverse of a matrix as dividing by the matrix. You can't divide by zero, and similarly you can't take the inverse of a "zero" matrix.